# How do I query three tables based on a single field

Tags: sql, select, database, relational

I have three tables in an SQL database.  This relational system was designed by someone else but I was asked to create a new query because he no longer works for the company.  I will use sample names for confidentiality purposes.

1. **customer**
   customer_id
   product_code
   product_color
   product_size
   ...
2. **customer_link**
   customer_id
   product_id
3. **customer_stats**
   product_id
   product_actual_product
   product_actual_color
   product_actual_size
   ...

This system was designed for users to enter information in the system and have multiple products for each customer.  In customer, the fields shown are all codes linked by customer_id from (1) to (2).  Two then can have multiple links between (2) and (3) based on multiple records in (2) with the same customer_id and different product_id's.  (3) has the linked product_id and the actual text for the codes listed in (1).

The bottom line is that I need a SELECT statement based on the fields in (1) but with the data stored in (3).  Wow I'm confused and could really use some help.

Comment: maybe you should also state what database system you are using.

Comment: Are you sure the Customer table contains information about product code, colour, size, etc?  If it does, then the design is probably horribly broken.  I'm sincerely hoping that's a copy'n'paste error of some sort!  (And I'm not entirely convinced by the columns in the customer stats table either...but I realize that this is a simulation of what's in the real database.)

Comment: It would help if you would put some sample data and the expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be pretty straight forward,

```
SELECT  a.*, c.*
FROM    customer a
        INNER JOIN customer_link b
            ON a.customer_ID = b.customer_ID
        INNER JOIN Customer_stats c
            ON b.product_id = c.product_id
```

To learn more about joins, see the link below

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)